# devExpress searchLookupEdit not setting value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have multiple searchLookupEdit controls on a form. All but one are working.

here is the code to populate one that is working

```
Private _list As sbList
_list = ag.ListByName("RMATroubleCode")
sluTroubleCode.Properties.DataSource = _list.Items

sluTroubleCode.EditValue = _item.TroubleCode.Value
```

here is the one that will not work

```
    Private Sub populate_SKUOrdered(ByRef ctl As SearchLookUpEdit)
        Dim ag As New cpAssemblyQuery()
        Dim l As List(Of cpAssembly) = ag.TopLevelAssemblies()

        ctl.Properties.DataSource = l
    End Sub

populate_SKUOrdered(sluCreateSKUOrdered)
 sluCreateSKUOrdered.EditValue = _item.SKU_OriginallyOrdered.Value
```

I have verified that  sluCreateSKUOrdered has a DisplayMember and ValueMember property set correctly. They are both set to "SKU" so that is pretty simple.

The dropdown does contain the expected # of items.
The SKU i am trying to set is 'RM45'. So thats pretty simple to verify. It is not a case of trailing or leading spaces...

Are there some trouble shooting steps I can take? I am confident this is a case of simple oversight, but I can not find anything on DevExpress to help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a ORM,  it is necessary to use the following code

```
ctl.Properties.DisplayMember = "SKU.Value"
    ctl.Properties.ValueMember = "SKU.Value"
```

The other controls were using interfaces, or simpler objects, so there was not a good analogy there.